# StackOverflowException when trying to create a form that begins minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is simple. I have this new form, and I just code this:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_Resize);

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
        else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want this form to begin minimized, and I want to show the taskbar icon only when the form is not minimized. But when I run this i receive a `StackOverflowException`. I think that the `ShowInTaskbar = false` is calling the resize method.

Comment: If ShowInTaskbar calling resize method then you can have Boolean flag that you set to true in Form1_Resize method if its false else return.

Comment: Seemd that this ShowInTaskBar update during form initialization/construction is the source of many problems. Look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390945/how-to-change-this-showintaskbar-for-a-form-showdialog-while-keeping-it-op)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your automatic minimization in the "Load" event, instead of the constructor.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_Resize);
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);

    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
        else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why this prevents a stack overflow, but as soon as I find out, I'll update the answer.  I've tested it after reproducing the issue and can confirm that it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can fix this instance by only adding your event handler after you minimise the form.

The other approaches (which will stop this problem occurring at any time) are for the event handler to remove itself from the event when it starts, and add itself back on just before it exits (so it doesn't get called when it makes a size change itself), or to use a bool member variable that is set to true while the event handler us executing so that it knows to ignore any events that it triggers itself.