# StackOverflowException whenever I minimize the window programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a small app that is supposed to start right into the system tray whenever it's opened. In terms of the system tray etc. everything works. Whenever I minimize the window by clicking the button on the top right, the app minimizes, hides the Taskbar and goes into the system tray. And if it click the tray icon, it opens again. Just like it should.

But if I set the window property to "minimized" in order to let it start minimized automatically, I immediately get a *System.StackOverflowException*.

Even if I set the property to normal and change it manually with the following code, I get the same Exception.

```
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

The Exception always happens at the "this.Hide()" part of this EventHandler:

```
     private void frmMain_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState) {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Hide();
        } else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState) {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;

        }
    }
```

Even if I delete the "this.Hide();" row, I still get the same Exception, but now it's just at the end of the method without any clues on why it might have happened.

Main method looks like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.frmMain_Resize);
        getSettings();
        startServer();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

Comment: ShowInTaskbar is a dangerous property.  There is no point in using it, when you Hide() the window then the task bar icon is already hidden.  So simply delete the assignments to solve your problem.

Comment: Couldn't manage to hide the taskbar icon with just Hide(), but your answer really helped me to figure out the problem. 
Apparently the window gets resized whenever the showInTaskbar property is changed, which leads to an infinite loop. 
Two posts really helped me out from there on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823588/why-is-showintaskbar-crashing-my-app-with-no-exception 

And this finally did the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640319/stackoverflowexception-when-trying-to-create-a-form-that-begins-minimized